# Google Sheet To Doc Hyperlink Display

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**Context:** I am inserting G Form Data into a G Sheet, which then appends a new row onto a table I have on a G Doc. The last column in the Google Doc Table I want to provide a Hyperlink with the word 'Edit'.

I want to achieve what .link does but it inserts the html which doesnt work in docs. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_link.asp

Here is my script directly inside the G Sheet (On Form Submit):

```
  // Grab the Table
  var body = DocumentApp.openById('theId').getBody(),
  searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE),
  element = searchElement.getElement(),
  table = element.asTable();

  // Wait for row insertion to finish, so that sheet.getLastRow() method gets the updated number of rows
  Utilities.sleep(1000); // 1 second  

  // Get the last row ID  
  var mySs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetId').getSheets()[0];
  var lastRowId = mySs.getLastRow();
  var hyperlink = mySs.getRange('L' + lastRowId).getValue();

  // Insert the Row
  var cells = [lastRowId, hyperlink];
    var addRow = table.appendTableRow();
    cells.forEach(function(e, i){
    addRow.insertTableCell(i, e);
  });

  body.saveAndClose();
```

So right now it directly adds the hyperlink to the google form. Whereas I want to switch the current hyperlink variable in the cells array to an actual hyper link That says 'Edit' that has the hyperlink variable URL.

I tried to add script data directly from the G Form *Example*

```
var hyperlink = '=HYPERLINK("www.google.com", "Google")';
```

which worked and inserted the Hyperlink to the G Sheet. The problem was it couldn't then take it to the G Doc. I think maybe because G Sheet formulas can't extract to G Doc Tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the method to directly give the link when the cell values is added. So how about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- After the cell values were added, it sets the link using `setLinkUrl()`.
- I think that `body.saveAndClose()` occurs an error. Please use `saveAndClose()` to the document.

#### Modified script :

```
// Grab the Table
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('theId');
var body = doc.getBody(),
searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE),
element = searchElement.getElement(),
table = element.asTable();

// Wait for row insertion to finish, so that sheet.getLastRow() method gets the updated number of rows
Utilities.sleep(1000); // 1 second

// Get the last row ID  
var mySs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetId').getSheets()[0];
var lastRowId = mySs.getLastRow();
var hyperlink = mySs.getRange('L' + lastRowId).getValue(); // Sample is '=HYPERLINK("www.google.com", "Google")'
// var hyperlink = '=HYPERLINK("www.google.com", "Google")'; // If the error related to LINK occurs, please use this line instead of above hyperlink.
var link = hyperlink.match(/"(.*?)"/g); // Added

// Insert the Row
var cells = [lastRowId, theDate, comment, link[1].replace(/"/g, "")]; // Modified
var addRow = table.appendTableRow();
cells.forEach(function(e, i){
  addRow.insertTableCell(i, e);
});
table.getCell(table.getNumRows() - 1, cells.length - 1).setLinkUrl(link[0].replace(/"/g, "")); // Added

doc.saveAndClose();
```

#### Note :

- `theDate` and `comment` are not declared in the script of your question.

  - Please check this again, before run this sample script.
- In this sample script, it supposes that the value retrieved by `mySs.getRange('L' + lastRowId).getValue()` is the string value like `=HYPERLINK("www.google.com", "Google")`. So the URL and link string are retrieved by the regex of `"(.*?)"`.

  - If the value retrieved by `mySs.getRange('L' + lastRowId).getValue()` is different from this, please modify the regex.
- If you want to change the index of LINK in the array of `cells`, please modify it.

#### Reference :

- [setLinkUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#setlinkurlurl)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

```
// Grab the Table
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('theId');
var body = doc.getBody(),
searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE),
element = searchElement.getElement(),
table = element.asTable();

// Wait for row insertion to finish, so that sheet.getLastRow() method gets the updated number of rows
Utilities.sleep(1000); // 1 second

// Get the last row ID  
var mySs = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetId').getSheets()[0];
var lastRowId = mySs.getLastRow();

// --- Following part was modified ---
var url = 'url.com'; // Added
var linkText = 'Edit'; // Added
// Insert the Row
var cells = [lastRowId, theDate, comment, linkText]; // Modified
var addRow = table.appendTableRow();
cells.forEach(function(e, i){
  addRow.insertTableCell(i, e);
});
table.getCell(table.getNumRows() - 1, cells.length - 1).setLinkUrl(url); // Modified

doc.saveAndClose();
```

Comment: The current cell contents of var hyperlink '.getRange' is just a URL at the moment. I can however easily change the format to your example.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this solution? Something like this:

var url = 'url.com';
var linkText = 'Edit';
var hyperlink = hyperlink(url, linkText);

Comment: @Bjaeg I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstand your comment, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Bjaeg Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.